# Android ContentResolver query giving wrong output

Tags: android

My app is not able to fetch any content from People.CONTENT_URI.
Insert is successful and the result is: "URI=content://contacts/people/15"
The cursor print is:

```
"cursor=>>>>> Dumping cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@d1caa72
<<<<<
position=-1
```

I tried using cursor moveToFirst after the query and the result log showed:

```
cursor=>>>>> Dumping cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@d1caa72
<<<<<
position=0
```

Code snippet:

```
import android.provider.Contacts.People;

final ContentResolver mResolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
mResolver.delete(People.CONTENT_URI, null, null);
final ContentValues valuse = new ContentValues();
valuse.put(People._ID, "1");
valuse.put(People.NAME, "name");
Uri uri = mResolver.insert(People.CONTENT_URI, valuse);
Log.d("MyApp","preparePeople: URI=" +uri);

private final String[] mPROJECTION = new String[] {
        People._ID, People.NAME
};
final Cursor c = mContext.getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI, mPROJECTION, null, null, null);
Log.i("MyApp","cursor=" + DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(c) + "  position=" + c.getPosition());
```

Please let me know what is wrong with my code snippet. The cursor output is not showing any of the values inserted.

Comment: "Please let me know what is wrong with my code snippet" -- you have not stated what your problem is. `position=0` is the proper outcome of a `moveToFirst()` call.

Comment: Question edited. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching data from cursor but you are not telling your cursor to fetch from which position, by default cursor points to -1 position.

So, you have to use,

```
c.moveToFirst();
```

After fetching cursor.

Comment: So should I use c.moveToFirst() before this line: final Cursor c = mContext.getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI, mPROJECTION, null,
                null, null);

Comment: No, not before, after having instance of Cursor c.

Comment: Even after that the output is not the items that were inserted: cursor=>>>>> Dumping cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@d1caa72
<<<<<
position=0